# use a usb docking station over powerline

Tags: usb, hdmi, docking-station, powerline-networking

I have a computer in a room away from my living room and I was thinking is it possible to for example use a docking station such as this (which has these inputs : HDMI, DVI, USB, VGA,....) which combines all these inputs into a usb and then use powerlines to connect that into my computer. My final goal is to have usb/ethernet/hdmi all from my PC connected to my living room via powerlines.

dockinng station :
[http://www.amazon.com/Plugable-UD-3900-Universal-2048x1152-Ethernet/dp/B00ECDM78E/ref=lp_778660_1_1?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1398981745&sr=1-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ECDM78E)

and connect the output usb to a powerline usb connector such as (or better brands with usb 2.0)

[http://www.amazon.com/NETGEAR-Powerline-200Mbps-PassThru-Adapter/dp/B009WG6LLA/ref=sr_1_3?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1398983611&sr=1-3&keywords=powerline+usb](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009WG6LLA)

So I can use it to attach keyboard, mouse and also use hdmi tv to it?

-There are also more powerline adaptors with 2 or 3 ethernets rather than usb ports. Is it possible for example to use a usb hub and then usb to ethernet convertor and then plug it into powerline adaptor and then get those usbs back at my computer.

thanks

Comment: Neither of those products have anything to do with Powerline networking. One is a dock that you plug in via USB to add extra ports to a PC and the other is a USB charger.

Comment: I posted the link wrongly! I corrected that.but the whole question is to use a docking which combine all features into a single usb and then use a usb over powerline to connect it to computer!

Comment: You can get a router with USB support hook that up to the PowerLine but I see no other way

Answer (score 0):

No, thats not really how this works. The USB port is meant for running a small subset of 'local' devices from the powerline networking device. This is closer to the storage/printer USB ports on a router, than a USB over IP device (which is essentially what you're looking at). It does not do 'true' usb over IP - it simply runs the device locally and shares it out.

You *could* plug in a USB over IP device to a regular, cheaper homeplug device and use that the way you are expecting this to work